# Laravel - Get row that has today between begin and end

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date, eloquent

I have a table that has two dates fields, `begin` and `end`.

I'm trying to get all rows that have begun but not yet ended. and if today is less than `begin`, they shouldn't be included. and if today is grater than `end` they shouldn't be included.

I'm using laravels eloquent. Here is what i've tried

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

$promos = \App\Models\LivePromo::
    where("begin", "<=", $now)
    ->where("end", ">=", $now)
    //Other conditions
    ->get();
```

This seemingly work, but it also selects rows that are greater have already ended.
How can i make this work as i expect?

#### EDIT

The `begin` column is a datetime column that signifies when the 'promo' should start, and the `end` column is a datetime column that signifies when the 'promo' should end. I'm just trying to get all valid promos for the current date and time

#### EDIT

Sample data

```
$now = '2017-02-24 10:29:10' // \Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

[image]

Comment: `>=` should be `<=` on your end row

Comment: @Farkie that doesn't work. i added an edit better explaining what im trying to achieve

Comment: Can you show us an example of what `Carbon::now()` is returning and an example of a row that is being returned that shouldn't be?

Comment: @RaymondAtivie both of those records you posted are valid? They both have a `begin` date in the past and an `end` date in the future?

Comment: @james i just realised my server time was one hour behind my client time. That caused some misunderstanding. the above code is valid. Sorry for the hassle guys. i'd delete post soon

Answer (score 0):

remove `=` from end date condition:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

$promos = \App\Models\LivePromo::
    where("begin", "<=", $now)
    ->where("end", ">", $now)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it might depend on your database engine.

Some engines require you to use the `whereDate`() method instead of plain old `where()`

```
$promos = LivePromo::whereDate("begin", "<=", $now)
    ->whereDate("end", ">", $now)
    ->get();
```